Pushdown Automaton accept all words belong to language over (a,b) where the first letter 'a' has half of the occurences of the second letter 'b'
Pushdown Automaton accept all words belong to language over (a,b) where the first letter 'a' has half of the occurences of the second letter 'b'.
Can someone help me with a JFLAP like digram of this Automaton?

This seems like your homework assignment. Nobody likes to do your home work for you. If you have any doubts or need clarifications, we are more than happy to help.

Hint: for each 'a', you need to match two 'b's. If 'a' = +2 (credit) and 'b' = -1 (debit), at the end, your balance should be exactly $0$.

Thank you. Yeh I had some challenges and was looking for some directions as to how this can be solved.

Does this answer your question? Construct Pushdown Automaton that accepts language $x\in{a,b}^*, a=2b$

Yes, @Hendrik it does but I think that the solution there is less clear then what suggested below. Thank you


Does anyone have any comments about the solution?

It represent the language {a^nb^2n} like abb,aabbbb,...
let take an example abb you are pussing two a's for every 'a' you see, into stack and popping them by matching with b's

I am not sure it is the same. In this case what is needed is that every word in every order of a and b with only one condition that number of a's will be half the number of b's.
For example the word abbbabbba is in the language. Can you say if the solution I suggested is the correct solution?

This answer is incorrect. The suggested PDA refuses $\mathsf{bab}$ which should be accepted.
